# Representing Functions as Types

Tags: function, haskell, coq, type-theory

A function can be a highly nested structure:

```
function a(x) {
  return b(c(x), d(e(f(x), g())))
}
```

First, wondering if a function has an *instance*. That is, the evaluation of the function being the instance of the function. In that sense, the type is the function, and the instance is the evaluation of it. If it can be, then how to model a function as a type (in some type-theory oriented language like Haskell or Coq).

It's almost like:

```
type a {
  field: x
  constructor b {
    constructor c {
      parameter: x
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm not on the right track. I know you can say a function has a [return] type. But I'm wondering if a function can be considered a type, and if so, how to model it as a type in a type-theory-oriented language, where it models the actual implementation of the function.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families)?

Comment: The structure you describe looks like a _syntax tree_ in a compiler or an interpreter.  There are various statements you can make about _types_ given that syntax tree – `c(x)` takes the single parameter to `a` and its return value is the first parameter to `b()`, so types must match up in those places – but I'm not used to seeing a syntax tree directly represented as a type like this.

Comment: What language are you asking about? You mention Haskell and Coq, and you provide an example of what looks like a Javascript function, as well as a type definition that I can't identify the language of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that types based directly on the implementation (let's call them "i-types") don't seem very useful, and we already have good ways of modelling them (called "programs" -- ha ha).

In your specific example, the full i-type of your function, namely:

```
type a {
  field: x
  constructor b {
    constructor c {
      parameter: x
    },
    constructor d {
      constructor e { 
        constructor f { 
          parameter: x 
        } 
        constructor g {
        }
    }
  }
}
```

is just a verbose, alternative syntax for the implementation itself.  That is, we could write this i-type (in a Haskell-like syntax) as:

```
itype a :: a x = b (c x) (d (e (f x) g))
```

On the other hand, we could convert your function *implementation* to Haskell term-level syntax directly to write it as:

```
a x = b (c x) (d (e (f x) g))
```

and the i-type and the implementation are exactly the same thing.

How would you use these i-types?  The compiler might use them by deriving argument and return types to type-check the program.  (Fortunately, there are well known algorithms, such as [Algorithm W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Algorithm_W), for simultaneously deriving and type-checking argument and return types from i-types of this sort.)  Programmers probably wouldn't use i-types directly -- they're too complicated to use for refactoring or reasoning about program behavior.  They'd probably want to look at the types derived by the compiler for the arguments and return type.

In particular, "modelling" these i-types at the type level in Haskell doesn't seem productive.  Haskell can already model them at the term level.  Just write your i-types as a Haskell program:

```
a x = b (c x) (d (e (f x) g))
b s t = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ length (s ++ t)
c = show
d = reverse
e c ds = show (sum ds + fromIntegral (ord c))
f n = if even n then 'E' else 'O'
g = [1.5..5.5]
```

and don't run it.  Congratulations, you've successfully modelled these i-types!  You can even use GHCi to query derived argument and return types:

```
> :t a
a :: Floating a => Integer -> a   -- "a" takes an Integer and returns a float
>
```

Now, you are perhaps imagining that there are situations where the implementation and i-type would diverge, maybe when you start introducing literal values.  For example, maybe you feel like the function `f` above:

```
f n = if even n then 'E' else 'O'
```

should be assigned a type something like the following, that doesn't depend on the specific literal values:

```
type f {
  field: n
  if_then_else {
    constructor even {    -- predicate
      parameter: n
    }
    literal Char          -- then-branch
    literal Char          -- else-branch
}
```

Again, though, you'd be better off defining an arbitrary term-level `Char`, like:

```
someChar :: Char
someChar = undefined
```

and modeling this i-type at the term-level:

```
f n = if even n then someChar else someChar
```

Again, as long as you don't run the program, you've successfully modelled the i-type of `f`, can query its argument and return types, type-check it as part of a bigger program, etc.

Comment: Minor point: H-M is not an algorithm, but a type system. Multiple type inference algorithms exist for H-M, mostly with cryptic names like Algorithm Z and Algorithm W.

Comment: Thanks...  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear exactly what you are aiming at, so I'll try to point at some related terms that you might want to read about.

A function has not only a return type, but a type that describes its arguments as well.  So the (Haskell) type of `f` reads "f takes an Int and a Float, and returns a List of Floats."

```
f :: Int -> Float -> [Float]
f i x = replicate i x
```

Types can also describe much more of the specification of a function.  Here, we might want the type to spell out that the length of the list will be the same as the first argument, or that every element of the list will be the same as the second argument.  Length-indexed lists (often called Vectors) are a common first example of Dependent Types.

You might also be interested in functions that take types as arguments, and return types.  These are sometimes called "type-level functions".  In Coq or Idris, they can be defined the same way as more familiar functions.  In Haskell, we usually implement them using [Type Families](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#type-families), or using Type Classes with [Functional Dependencies](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#functional-dependencies).

Returning to the first part of your question, [Beta Reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Beta_reduction) is the process of filling in concrete values for each of the function's arguments.  I've heard people describe expressions as "after reduction" or "fully reduced" to emphasize some stage in this process.  This is similar to a function Call Site, but emphasizes the expression & arguments, rather than the surrounding context.